# How to extract the value by providing the key of an array in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, associative-array

I have the following result set retrieved from the database. How should i extract the value in the **employeeName** key?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [employeeName] => John
            [designation] => Assistant Accountant
            [rlevel] => Level 3
            [comments] => LOL
            [employeeCompany] => BDL
            [employeeCompanyCode] => 
            [uNo] => 41201
            [uCompany] => BOD
            [employeeNo] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: `$array[0]['employeeName']`?

Comment: thank you! it worked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call:

```
$value = $array[0]["employeeName"];
```

Comment: yes! it worked! thanks!! :)

Comment: You are welcome. You can click "Accept answer" checkbox on the left to not attract more people to this question as it stays open until you do so. Cheers.